# Make code faster

Tags: r

I have two datasets "consult" and "details" of different length (consult is ~1 million rows, details is ~350K rows - 20 variables each dataset) which have a column (ref) that allows me to cross-link these two datasets.
What the code is meant to do is to extract the value in consult$id where consult$ref equals details$ref

I have written this:

```
x <- as.character(levels(factor(details$ref)))
case<- character(0)
system.time( for(i in 1:length(x)){
case[i]<- as.character(consult$id[ consult$ref==x[i] ][1])
} )
```

I also tried

```
x <- as.character(levels(factor(details$ref)))
case<- list()
system.time( for(i in 1:length(x)){
  case[[i]]<- as.character(consult$id[ consult$ref==x[i] ] )
} )
```

But the run-time is pretty much the same (~15secs for x[1:100]).
I understand that the dataset is kinda large, but it would take ~14-15 hours to run through the whole dataset, which seems a little excessive. I could let it run overnight (although have few datasets like this and it would take me ages in the end) - just seems a waste of time and was hoping someone could suggest a faster way of doing this. 
Many thanks!
Marco

Comment: Maybe you should use `data.table` package and then join this two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
consult[consult$ref%in%details$ref, "id"]
```

Comment: This was amazing! It worked a treat!!!! Can not believe how fast it is! Many, many thanks!